# vertical left navigation with flyout submenus

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am looking to be able to run navigation down the lefthand side of the page with submenus appearing on the right side/border of the navigation (z-index so as not to push the main content out of the way).
Does anyone have a site/code link (codepen) or perhaps a code snippet that could assist? I am looking for an onclick rather than a hover event for the submenus to appear...
The first submenu level is only using .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content and not any jquery, not really bothered if it needs to be jscript or jquery. Many Thanks

```
<style>
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
html, body {height: 100%;}
body {background: #fff; padding: 0; margin: 0; font-family: Myriad-Pro, Arial, 'Varela Round', sans-serif; font-size: 16px;}

.quotation-window {display: flex; height: 100%}
.window-container {display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap; width: 100%;}
.header-one {display: flex; width: 100%; background-color: #dbdbdb; padding: 20px 10px;}
.header-two {display: flex; width: 100%; background-color: #afafaf; padding: 20px 10px;}
.content-container {display: flex; width: 100%; height: 100%}
.content-left {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #3f51b5;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    min-width: 80px;
    align-content: flex-start;
    height: 100%;
    width: 9vw;
}
.content-right {display: flex; background-color: #6d6d6d; padding: 20px 10px; width: 95%;}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #3f51b5;
    color: #fff;
}
ul li ul.submenu {display: none;}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown-content li a {
    display: flex;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 8px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li a:active {background-color: #3f51b5;  color: white;}
/*li a:hover:not(.active) {background-color: #ffcc01; color: black;}*/

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
.dropdown li {height: 4vh; color: #000;}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 999;
    left: 8.5vw;
    top: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
.dropdown-content-submenu {

    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 999;
    left: 11.1vw;
    top: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: flex-start;
}
.dropdown-submenu:hover .dropdown-content-submenu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: flex-start;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) and (min-width: 340px) {
    .quotation-window {display: flex; height: 100%}
    .content-container {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .content-left {
        height: fit-content;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .content-right {
        padding: 20px 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    ul {display: inline-flex;}
    .dropdown {display: inline-flex;}
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        width: 80%;
    }
}
</style>

<section class="quotation-window">

    <div class="window-container">
        <div class="header-one">header 1</div>
        <div class="header-two">header 2</div>
        <div class="content-container">
            <div class="content-left">
                <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li><a href="#home" class="dropdown">New</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-content">
                            <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-submenu">submenu navigation 1</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-content-submenu">
                                    <li>submenu navigation 1.1</li>
                                    <li>submenu navigation 1.2</li>
                                    <li>submenu navigation 1.3</li>
                                    <li>submenu navigation 1.4</li>
                                    <li>submenu navigation 1.5</li>
                                </ul>                            
                            </li>
                            <li>submenu navigation 2</li>
                            <li>submenu navigation 3</li>
                            <li>submenu navigation 4</li>
                            <li>submenu navigation 5</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#news">Existing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Inventory</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="content-right">right column content</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Classic's Blog</title>
<style>
nav ul {list-style-type: none; margin:0; padding:0; width: 200px; background-color: #f1f1f1; position: fixed;height: 100%}
nav ul li {min-width: 200px; font-size:14px;}
nav ul li a {display: block; color: #000; text-decoration: none; padding: 16px 0 16px 16px;}
ul li:hover > a {color: white; background-color: #555;}

.dropdown-content {
    min-width: 150px;
    display: none;
    left: 200px;
    float:left;
    position: absolute;
    font-size:14px;
    margin-top: -48px;
}
.dropdown-content a {
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 16px 0 16px 16px;
}
.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-content {
    display: inline-block;
}
.main {
  margin-left: 250px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<nav>
<ul>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Menu item 1</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-content">
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Menu item 11</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-content">
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Menu item 111</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-content">
                            <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Menu item 1111</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-content">
                                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Menu item 11111</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="">Menu item 11112</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="">Menu item 11113</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="">Menu item 11114</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Menu item 1112</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-content">
                  <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Menu item 11121</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="">Menu item 11122</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="">Menu item 11123</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="">Menu item 11124</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>                
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Menu item 112</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Menu item 113</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Menu item 12</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Menu item 13</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Menu item 14</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  <li><a href="">Menu item 2</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Menu item 3</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-content">
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Menu item 31</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-content">
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Menu item 311</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-content">
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Menu item 3111</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-content">
                            <li><a href="">Menu item 31111</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Menu item 31112</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Menu item 31113</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Menu item 31114</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Menu item 312</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Menu item 313</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Menu item 314</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Menu item 32</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu item 33</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu item 34</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Menu item 4</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>

<div class="main">
  <h2>Sidenav Example</h2>
  <p>This sidenav is always shown.</p>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find code that does what i need.
It is here if anyone is interested in looking for vertical leftnav
https://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/9m60mx6r/7/

```
<style>
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
.container {
    height:100%;
}
a {
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #fff;
    padding:0px 0px 20px 0px;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    height:100%;
}
li {
    padding:20px 20px 0 20px;
    width:100%;
    color:#fff;
}
.container ul {height:100%;}
.container > ul {
    width:250px;
    background-color:#224490;
    position:relative;
    overflow:visible;
}
.container > ul > li {}
.container > ul > li:hover {background-color:#0f1e41;}
.container > ul > li > ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    right:-250px;
    top:0;
    width:250px;
    background-color:#18316a;
}
.container > ul > li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}
.container > ul > li > ul >li:hover {background-color:#0f1e41;}
.container > ul > li > ul > li > ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    right:-250px;
    top:0;
    width:250px;
    background-color:#112551;
}
.container > ul > li > ul > li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
.container > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li:hover {background-color:#0f1e41;}
.container > ul > li > ul > li ul li ul li {
    border-bottom:1px dotted #fff;
    padding:20px;
}    
</style>

<div class="container">        
            <ul class="">

                <li class="">
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Client Advice</a>
                    <ul class="">

                        <li class=""><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Pre-advice</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="#">Strategy & Technical</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="#">Research</a></li>
                        <li class="">
                            <a href="#">APL & Products</a>
                            <ul class="parent">
                                <li >
                                    <a href="#">
                                        Approved Product List                                        
                                    </a>

                                    <ul class="child">
                                        <li >Platforms</li>
                                        <li >Managed Funds</li>
                                        <li >Wealth Protection</li>
                                        <li >Listed Securities</li>
                                        <li >Wealth Protection</li>
                                        <li >Listed Securities</li>
                                        <li >Listed Securities</li>
                                    </ul>

                                </li>
                                <li ><a href="#">Model Portfolios</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="#">Non-approved Products</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class=""><a href="#">Implementation</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="#">Review</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="#">Execution Only</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li ><a href="#">Personal Development</a></li>
                <li ><a href="#">Practice</a></li>
                <li ><a href="#">News</a></li>
            </ul>
        
    </div>

<script>
$('.child').hide(); //Hide children by default

        $('.parent').children().click(function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).children('.child').slideToggle('slow');
            $(this).find('span').toggle();
        });
</script>
```